# SQL using multiple tables and using several SUM functions

Tags: sql, sum

I have looked over several posts that are relative but I cannot figure out how to apply them to my situation.

```
SELECT [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityID],
       [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityName],
       [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityDate],
       [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityPlaces],
       [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityPrice],
       SUM([LeisureActivities].[dbo].[bookings].[bookingPlaces]) AS 'bookingTotal',
       SUM([LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings].[tempPlaces]) AS 'tempPlacesReserved'

FROM   [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities],
       [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[bookings],
       [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings]

WHERE ([LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityID]=[LeisureActivities].[dbo].[bookings].[activityID] 
    AND [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityID]=[LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings].[tempActivityID]) 
    AND [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityDate] > GetDate ()

GROUP BY [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityID],
         [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityName],
         [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityDate],
         [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityPlaces],
         [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityPrice];
```

As you can see this refers to 3 tables, `activities`, `bookings` and `tempbookings`. The `tempbookings` table also contains a `tempReservedDate` field which contains a datetime datatype, I need my SUM calculation for tempPlaces only to SUM those records that have a `tempReservedDate` in the future, those in the past just ignore (similar to how I'm already controlling the activities by displaying only those with a future date) the SUM also needs to group these by each activity.

I believe I need to put in my "WHERE" section something like

```
[LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings].[tempReservedDate] > GetDate ()
```

I just don't know where to put it to make it work without applying that to my whole query as it only needs to apply to the `tempPlaces`.

I hope I've managed to explain what I mean but please ask if it doesn't make sense, although I am aware that often you wouldn't format it how I have (with the [] etc.) but for the program that uses these queries it has to be done in this particular format.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a conditional sum in the `select` clause:

```
SUM(case when [tempbookings].[tempReservedDate] > GetDate()
                then tempBookings.tempPlaces
           end) as FutureTempPlaces
```

Also, you should learn how to better format your code and use sensible aliases (such as `tb` for `tempBookings`).

Comment: Thank you for your response - This is a good start however if there are currently no records for the actvitiy in the tempbookings table for that particular activity then the activity record doesn't display at all. The query should return 3 different activities and then display the "FutureTempPlaces" for only one of the activities as that is the only one that has a tempbookings record at present - apologies for not mentioning this before.